# Pandas - First find header, then only load certain columns on an Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am trying to read multiple large Excel files with Pandas and combine them into a single CSV and only need data from one data sheet from each file.

Within this data sheet, there are a number of filler rows that I do not need data from - basically, the data that I need starts at different places in each file. The first column of the data that I need is called `Row Labels`.

Is there a way I can have Pandas pull data below the column headed with `Row Labels` and four columns to the right of that?

Right now, this is what I've been trying to no avail:

```
for f in glob.glob("../Test/Drawsheet*.xlsx"):
    df_temp = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    if 'PVT' in df_temp.sheet_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(df_temp, 'PVT', index_col=None, usecols='Row Labels')
        #df.to_csv('your_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
        #df = df_temp.parse('PVT')
        all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
```

Comment: Read in the header, figure out where the columns are, then read in the file with `usecols` specifying the 5 indices you need.

Comment: So the columns are different for each file. Sometimes it may start in Column G and other times in Column H, for example.

Comment: Which is why you read just one line (`nrows=1`) (very fast) then do `idx = df.columns.get_loc('Row Labels')`, then you read the whole file specifying `usecols=[*range(idx, idx+5)]`

Comment: Any idea how to do this if the rows start say on row 10 rather than row 1?

Comment: add `skiprows=10` or however many rows it needs to be,.

Comment: I get the concept, but I don't necessarily know how many rows/columns it needs to be. It could vary from file to file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what your files look like (e.g. up to the first couple of actual rows)

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Pandas to just load the first `20` rows (assuming your header is there). You can then locate the `Row Labels` value and then use this location to load the whole Excel file. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'input.xlsx'
sheet = 'Sheet1'

df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet, nrows=20)
header_loc = df[df == 'Row Labels'].dropna(axis=1, how='all').dropna(how='all')
row = header_loc.index.item()
column = header_loc.columns.item()
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet, skiprows=row+1, usecols=list(range(column, column+5)))
```

---

If you had a CSV, the following approach would work. It reads each row of your file and attempts to locate `Row Labels` in a parsed row. This will fail until the actual header row is reached. When it does, the column index is used to pick your required columns to the right of it. The `skiprows` parameters is used to tell pandas to skip to the correct header row in the file, and `usecols` can be correctly specified with the next 4 column names.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

filename = 'input.csv'

with open(filename, newline='') as f_csv:
    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f_csv)):
        try:
            col = row.index('Row Labels')
            break
        except ValueError:
            continue

df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=row_number, usecols=row[col:col+4])
print(df)
```

Comment: Will this translate to .xlsx? I do not yet have them in .csv

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. Pandas can be made to just load the first rows and locate the header. The whole file can then be loaded using that.